# Button switching using python (Tkinter)

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

What I'm trying to do is to switch buttons, basically.

When button 1 is pressed it gets destroyed and then button 2 launches.

I'm having an error, here's the code.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('TEST')
def D1():
    B.destroy()
    Launch2()

def D2():
    B2.destroy()
    Launch1()

def Launch1():
    B = Button (root, text = 'BUTTON 1', command = D1)
    B.pack()


def Launch2():
    B2 = Button (root, text = 'BUTTON 2', command = D2)
    B2.pack()


Launch1()
mainloop()
```

Error :

```
        Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1541, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\youse\Desktop\Tkinter Testing GUI.py", line 5, in D1
    B.destroy()
NameError: global name 'B' is not defined
```

Comment: The error is telling the truth. There's nowhere in your code where you're creating a global variable named `B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the lines, global B and global B2 to the code in the following way:

```
def Launch1():
    global B     # Make B a global variable
    B = Button (root, text = 'BUTTON 1', command = D1)
    B.pack()


def Launch2():
    global B2    # Make B2 a global variable
    B2 = Button (root, text = 'BUTTON 2', command = D2)
    B2.pack()
```

The program now works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

The variable B in the function Launch1 is defined locally only in that function
The same is true for B2.
Hence the D1 function does not have access to B and D2 does not have access to B2.

You need to find a way to make function D see variable B
One solution is to create B outside the functions then use global B in the two functions launch1 and D - then do the same for B2
This is not a recommended solution, normally you would have a class defined that could hold B, B2 and the four functions then there would be no need for global variables